# Concatenate strings and integers of multiple variables using a loop and call the variable

Tags: python

I am newbie, apologies if I used wrong terminology
I have a ton of variables (named with strings and integers) in my code and want to make a simple loop to call all the variables easily.

Example:

```
acc1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
acc2 = ["John", "Doe", "Example", "code"]
c = [1, 2]

for i in c:
    something = 'acc'+str(i)
    # convert string to list
    print(something[0])
```

I'd like to concatenate letters in acc1 and acc2 in a loop. So that I can work on a certain variable in the loop.

I am not sure if what I did is correct. I created strings to form the variable name, which is not working out.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - I think you are asking how to dynamically look up the symbol table to convert `"acc1"`  to the variable `acc1` ([reasonably easy to do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/1270789)), but I think the problem is why do you have `acc1`, `acc2` instead of a list `acc[]` in the first place.

Comment: I referred this as an example. My original code has a different naming scheme (including strings and numbers).

Comment: Do you want to concatenate like John1, Doe2, or J1, o2, h3, n4?

Comment: @Programmer No, I want to use the loop to call the list items in individual variables

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Sree can you please tell me what the expected result is?

Comment: @Swagrim I want to create a loop to access list items in a multiple variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to dynamically access variables defines in your current scope, you could try using the [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function. This will return a dictionary with the name of the variables in the current scope as the key and their value as the value of the dictionary.

```
acc1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
acc2 = ["John", "Doe", "Example", "code"]
c = [1, 2]

variables = locals()

for i in c:
    variable_name = "acc" + str(i)
    
    print(variables.get(variable_name))
```

On a side note, you might want to look into f-strings if you're using python 3.5 or greater. It's possible to simply replace the string concatenation with `f"acc{i}"`

Comment: Thank you.  I resorted to {eval("acc"+str(i))}.